# How can I switch to TLS after the initial handshake with BlueSocket?

Tags: mysql, swift, sockets, ssl, tcp

I'm trying to implement the MySQL client/server protocol in Swift, using [BlueSocket](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/BlueSocket).

From what I understand, MySQL requires the initial connection to be over plain TCP, and then connection can be switched to use TLS. However, [BlueSSLService](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/BlueSSLService), which enabled SSL/TLS with BlueSocket, requires the socket to be configured to use TLS before calling `Socket.connect`.

To create an unencrypted socket I'm using:

```
import Socket

let socket = try! Socket.create()
try! socket.connect(to: "127.0.0.1", port: 3306)
```

With this I'm able to perform the initial MySQL handshake. However, if I try to use TLS, like this:

```
import Socket
import SSLService

let sslConfig = SSLService.Configuration()
let socket = try! Socket.create()
socket.delegate = try! SSLService(usingConfiguration: sslConfig)
try! socket.connect(to: "127.0.0.1", port: 3306) // ERROR: SSLHandshake
```

I get an error.

Is it possible to initially connect to a MySQL server over TLS? If not (as it appears), how can I switch start using TLS after the initial handshake (and [SSLRequest](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/8.0.12/page_protocol_connection_phase_packets_protocol_ssl_request.html) packet)?